# How can I return all songs by Album (collectionID) from Apple itunes search API

Tags: ios, xcode, itunes

I want to do something like this:

https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?collectionid=211192863&entity=song

But it doesn't return the songs

I'm pretty sure they have such parameter since it is a pretty basic one

any tips are appreciated

**Edit:**

it seems I can pass ID also, but I don't know if I can trust it once I usd id input for artist search as well

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are very close - the proper API request should be:
https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=211192863&entity=song

Note, the first result returned is the Collection meta data, each of the following 12 results are the track meta data.

Comment: If an album only appears in the store of a specific country, you need to add the `country` param this to your search: e.g: http://itunes.apple.com/lookup?country=DE&entity=song&id=504269814

Answer (score -1):

Your url is wrong, for search API url you should see below:

https://itunes.apple.com/search?id=211192863&entity=song&media=music

enjoy!!!